# React-Redux: App gets stuck until Touch Interaction

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-ios

In my React-Native app (on iOS), I am using Redux and Redux-Thunk to manage the state of API request. When I initially load my data like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchFirstData();
  }
```

The app get's stuck. In the log I see, that the requests pending action gets dispatched, but nothing happens after it. Only after I do *any* touch interaction on the screen, the request success action gets dispatched and everything works fine. As a workaround, I call the function like this which works as intended:

```
  render() {
    if (this.props.requests.length === 0) {
      this.props.fetchFirstData();
    }
```

But I would like to figure out what's wrong. My `actions.js` looks like this but I don't think that the mistake is here.

```
function foiRequestsError(error) {
  return {
    type: 'FOI_REQUESTS_ERROR',
    error,
  };
}

function foiRequestsPending() {
  return {
    type: 'FOI_REQUESTS_PENDING',
  };
}

function foiRequestsSuccess(requests) {
  return {
    type: 'FOI_REQUESTS_SUCCESS',
    requests,
  };
}

function foiRequestsFetchData(url) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(foiRequestsPending());

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.status);
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(requests => dispatch(foiRequestsSuccess(requests)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(foiRequestsError(error.message)));
  };
}

const ORIGIN = 'XXX';

function foiRequestsFetchFirstData() {
  return foiRequestsFetchData(`${ORIGIN}/XXX`);
}

function foiRequestsFetchMoreData(nextUrl) {
  return foiRequestsFetchData(`${ORIGIN}${nextUrl}`);
}

export { foiRequestsFetchFirstData, foiRequestsFetchMoreData };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there's a problem with remote debugging: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679 and setTimeout fixes it:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }
    setTimeout(() => null, 0); // workaround for issue-6679
    return response;
  })
```